# Java Android modifies member variables from Callback thread

Tags: java, android, rest, callback

Basically, I am trying to get some value from the Api callback response, then assign those value to some of my member variables, but It seems like the program has to run over my getPatientRecord() method each time before it could go to my call, which I have never encountered before.

The Log output result is :
viewPatient: paitient method
viewPatient: secondHello worldnullnull
100SN9 - David Hello H M H 1971-08-09

This is my code:

```
public class ViewPatientRecord extends AppCompatActivity{
TextView tvName, tvGender, tvBirthDate, tvAddress;
String pGender, pAddress, pBirthdate;
String pName = "Hello world";
Patient myPatient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_patient_record);

    tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);
    tvGender = findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
    tvBirthDate = findViewById(R.id.tvDb);
    tvAddress = findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);

    myPatient= new Patient();
    try {
        getPatientRecord();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void getPatientRecord() throws InterruptedException {
    SharedPreferences myPre = getSharedPreferences("PatientRecord", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(myPre.getString("uuid",null)!=null){
        retrievePatientByUuid(myPre.getString("uuid",null));
        Log.d("viewPatient", "second"+pName+pGender+pBirthdate);
        tvName.setText(pName);
        tvGender.setText(pGender);
        tvBirthDate.setText(pBirthdate);
        tvAddress.setText(pAddress);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(ViewPatientRecord.this, "Something went wrong, please contact the administrator for help!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void retrievePatientByUuid(String uuid) throws InterruptedException {
    RestApi api = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RestApi.class);
    Log.d("viewPatient", "paitient method");

    Call<Patient> call = api.getPatientByUUID(uuid, null);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Patient>() {
        private volatile Patient obj = new Patient();
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Patient> call, Response<Patient> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                Patient patient = response.body();
                if (patient != null) {
                    if (!patient.getDisplay().isEmpty()) {
                        pName = patient.getDisplay();
                        pGender = patient.getPerson().getGender();
                        pBirthdate = patient.getPerson().getBirthdate();
                        Log.d("viewPatient", pName.toString() + " H " + pGender.toString() + " H " + pBirthdate.toString() + " ?? ");
                        pAddress = "";
                    } else {
                            Log.d("viewPatient", "no results");
                        }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewPatientRecord.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ViewPatientRecord.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Patient> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem. The call is done in `retrievePatientByUuid` which is called by `getPatientRecord`. So yes, you have to go through `getPatientRecord`. The call is async. It's in the callback that you should set your TextViews :

```
    tvName.setText(pName);
    tvGender.setText(pGender);
    tvBirthDate.setText(pBirthdate);
    tvAddress.setText(pAddress);
```

Comment: You are right, I should set the textview in my Callback thread instead of main thread. Thank you !!!

Comment: The callback thread is the main thread. You can only change views from the main thread. You can try this using an AsyncTask and you'll get an error